# How can I load external layout files using RazorEngine?

Tags: razor, viewengine

I've been trying for days (really, days) to use "external" files (provided from a different server using an ashx handler) as layouts in Razor.

```
@{
    Layout = "http://someServer/templates.ashx?path=/my/template.cshtml";
}
```

This gives me an error about the path having to be a virtual one.

I've tried everything I could think of: `VirtualPathProviders`, custom `RazorViewEngines`, etc.

Nothing helps, has anyone done this or can someone give me a hint?

Comment: A VirtualPathProvider should work.  The string that gets passed to the VPP will still need to look like a virtual path.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, the VirtualPathProvider somehow overrides the default one, so the engine tries to load all views from the external location (-> with the custom VirtualPathProvider).

Comment: Make the custom VPP forward normal paths to the default one.

Comment: Ok.. how do I do this? (give it as answer, I'll accept it ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `VirtualPathProvider` that handles virtual paths that start with a magic token and passes all other paths to its [`Previous` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.previous.aspx).
For example:

```
public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath) {
    if (virtualPath.StartsWith("~/MySpecialTemplateServer"))
        return new MyServerVirtualFile(virtualPath);
    else
        return Previous.GetFile(virtualPath);
}
```